# Почему высота ячейки в таблице внезапно увеличилась?

Tags: css

Делаю игру на javascript. Все уже готово, но возникла проблема с CSS. Картинка, помещенная в ячейку таблицы, почему-то увеличивает высоту этой ячейки на 3px. Размеры вроде бы заданы корректно, в чем дело?

Пример:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  border-spacing:0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border: 1px solid black;    
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

img {
  width:18px;
  height:18px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src='http://imgn.dt00.net/2284/2284746_vb.jpg' /></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3c85/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пропиши для `img` `display:block;`

зы. по умолчанию img отображается как display:inline-block

Comment: Действительно, не знал. Спасибо. Все равно не понял, пусть даже inline-block, откуда берутся лишние пиксели?

Comment: display:inline-block получает этот отступ из-за размера шрифта, в твоем случает, если прописать для td font-size:0, то отсуп тоже уйдет